# Admob with Surfaceview crashes

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview, banner-ads

I want to add Admob Banner ad with SurfaceView but it gives NullPointerException, 
Here is code:

```
private AdView mAdView;
private LinearLayout ll;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
ll.addView(mAdView);
ll.addView(new GamePanel(this));
setContentView(ll);
}
```

GamePanel is a class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder

Error says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.binnat.zigzag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
```

line 52: mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that view in your layout yet so find the `Adview` in your LinerLayout.

```
mAdView = (AdView) ll.findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

Edit:

You can also move your `setContentView` call just to after you've created your `LinearLayout`:

```
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot to find my mistake, actually i created banner ad in xml also. I deleted it from xml and tried with code and it worked